# A question about uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued continuous function on $\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$. Prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

I have no idea about this question. Could somebody help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)|<\frac\epsilon2$ for $|x|>M$. What can you say about the restriction of $f$ to $(M,\infty)$, to $(-\infty,M)$ and to $[-M-1,M+1]$? (Note that $[-M+1,M+1]$ is closed and bounded)